# How to get checksums for strided patterns

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, checksum

I have a 64 bit number (but only the 42 low order bits are used) and need to computer the sum of the **4** bits at `n`, `n+m`, `n+m*2` and `n+m*3` (note: anything that can produce a sum >4 is invalid) for some fixed m and every value of n that places all the bits in the number

as an example using `m=3` and given the 16-bit number

```
0010 1011 0110 0001
```

I need to compute

```
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3
```

Does anyone have any (cool) ideas for ways to do this? I'm fine with bit twiddling.

---

My current thought is to make bit shifted copies of the input to align the values to be summed and then build a logic tree to do a 4x 1bit adder.

```
v1 = In;
v2 = In<<3;
v3 = In<<6;
v4 = In<<9;

a1 = v1 ^ v2;
a2 = v1 & v2;
b1 = v3 ^ v4;
b2 = v3 & v4;
c2 = a1 & b1;
d2 = a2 ^ b2;

o1 = a1 ^ b1;
o2 = c2 ^ d2;
o4 = a2 & b2;
```

This does end up with the bits of the result spread across 3 different ints but oh well.

*edit: as it happens I need the histogram of the sums so doing a [bit-count](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) of `o4`, `o2&o1`, `o2` and `o1` gives me what I want.*

---

a second solution uses a perfect hash function

```
arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   out[i] = arr[(In & 0b1001001001) % 30]; 
   In >>= 1;
}
```

This works by noting that the 4 selected bits can only take on 16 patterns and that (by guess and check) they can be hashed into 0-15 using mod 30. From there, a table of computed values gives the needed sum. As it happens only 3 of the 4 strides I need work this way.

---

p.s.

Correct trumps fast. Fast trumps clear. I expect to be running this millions of time.

Comment: your code is not very generic since the number of "v*" would vary with your m. Also, you would have to repeat this method for every [0;m] to get your full result vector.

Comment: I known in advance what the stride is, I just have several value I will need to work with. I can generalize the code but it wouldn't be as clear.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your code.  Can you do a manual calculation with a few iterations of your 16-bit example?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am crazy, but I am having fun :D
This solution is based upon the usage of data parallelism and faking a vector cpu without actually using SSE intrinsics or anything similar.

```
unsigned short out[64];
const unsigned long long mask      = 0x0249024902490249ul;
const unsigned long long shiftmask = 0x0001000100010001ul;

unsigned long long t = (unsigned short)(in >> 38) | (unsigned long long)(unsigned short)(in >> 39) > 40) > 41) << 48;
t &= mask;
*((unsigned long long*)(out + 38)) = (t & shiftmask) + (t >> 3 & shiftmask) + (t >> 6 & shiftmask) + (t >> 9 & shiftmask);

[... snipsnap ...]

t = (unsigned short)(in >> 2) | (unsigned long long)(unsigned short)(in >> 3) > 4) > 5) << 48;
t &= mask;
*((unsigned long long*)(out + 2)) = (t & shiftmask) + (t >> 3 & shiftmask) + (t >> 6 & shiftmask) + (t >> 9 & shiftmask);

t = (unsigned short)in | (unsigned long long)(unsigned short)(in >> 1) << 16;
t &= mask;
*((unsigned int*)out) = (unsigned int)((t & shiftmask) + (t >> 3 & shiftmask) + (t >> 6 & shiftmask) + (t >> 9 & shiftmask));
```

---

By reordering the computations, we can further reduce the execution time significantly, since it drastically reduces the amount of times that something is loaded into the QWORD. A few other optimizations are quite obvious and rather minor, but sum up to another interesting speedup.

```
unsigned short out[64];
const unsigned long long Xmask = 0x249024902490249ull;
const unsigned long long Ymask = 0x7000700070007u;

unsigned long long x = (in >> 14 & 0xFFFFu) | (in >> 20 & 0xFFFFu) > 26 & 0xFFFFu) > 32) << 48;
unsigned long long y;
y = x & Xmask;
y += y >> 6;
y += y >> 3;
y &= Ymask;
out[32] = (unsigned short)(y >> 48);
out[26] = (unsigned short)(y >> 32);
out[20] = (unsigned short)(y >> 16);
out[14] = (unsigned short)(y      );

x >>= 1;
y = x & Xmask;
y += y >> 6;
y += y >> 3;
y &= Ymask;
out[33] = (unsigned short)(y >> 48);
out[27] = (unsigned short)(y >> 32);
out[21] = (unsigned short)(y >> 16);
out[15] = (unsigned short)(y      );

[snisnap]

x >>= 1;
y = x & Xmask;
y += y >> 6;
y += y >> 3;
y &= Ymask;
out[37] = (unsigned short)(y >> 48);
out[31] = (unsigned short)(y >> 32);
out[25] = (unsigned short)(y >> 16);
out[19] = (unsigned short)(y      );

x >>= 1;
x &= 0xFFFF000000000000ul;
x |= (in & 0xFFFFu) | (in >> 5 & 0xFFFFu) > 10 & 0xFFFFu) << 32;
y = x & Xmask;
y += y >> 6;
y += y >> 3;
y &= Ymask;
out[38] = (unsigned short)(y >> 48);
out[10] = (unsigned short)(y >> 32);
out[ 5] = (unsigned short)(y >> 16);
out[ 0] = (unsigned short)(y      );

[snipsnap]

x >>= 1;
y = x & Xmask;
y += y >> 6;
y += y >> 3;
y &= Ymask;
out[ 9] = (unsigned short)(y >> 16);
out[ 4] = (unsigned short)(y      );
```

Running times for 50 million executions in native c++ (all ouputs verified to match ^^) compiled as a 64 bit binary on my pc:
Array based solution:     ~5700 ms
Naive hardcoded solution: ~4200 ms
The first solution:       ~2400 ms
The second solution:      ~1600 ms

Comment: nice. clean. OTOH I need really blazing fast as this is part of the inner most loop of a tree search algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't work. He only wants four bits in each sum. Also, the % operator is best avoided, as it is usually terribly slow.

Comment: I do not see anything that indicates that he would only want 4 bits per sum? "[...] computer the sum of the bits at [...]"

yeah % may be rather slow, and "c[i] ...; if(++i == m) i = m;" will probably be faster (although you need to 0 i out between the loops then)

Comment: % is now removed - the whole thing is now pointer instead of array based

Comment: A little oops... after your rework of the question I understood what you wanted the first time >.>

Comment: In looking at that it still has the problem that c[0] is the sum of 6 bits and I want exactly 4.

Comment: I probably have an obnoxious amount of fun with this^^

Comment: The full code of the updated test application can be found over there: http://pastebin.com/f573c0c2

Comment: If you are willing to spend ~0.5kb of memory, you can speed your perfect hash solution up to be the fastest of all (~1500 ms):  
you just need to precompile all 586 possible solutions and leave out your modulo 30.

Comment: how do you get 586 solutions?

Comment: take your perfect hash solution, remove the "% 30" and make arr large enough to allow for arr[0x1001001001]

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion that I don't want to code right now is to use a loop, an array to hold partial results, and constants to pick up the bits m at a time.

```
loop 
   s[3*i] += x & (1 << 0);
   s[3*i+1] += x & (1 << 1);
   s[3*i+2] += x & (1 << 2);
   x >> 3;
```

This will pick too many bits in each sum. But you can also keep track of the intermediate results and subtract from the sums as you go, to account for the bit that may not be there anymore.

```
loop 
   s[3*i] += p[3*i]   = x & (1 << 0);
   s[3*i+1] += p[3*i+1] = x & (1 << 1);
   s[3*i+2] += p[3*i+2] = x & (1 << 2);

   s[3*i] -= p[3*i-10];
   s[3*i+1] -= p[3*i-9];
   s[3*i+2] -= p[3*i-8];
   x >> 3;
```

with the appropriate bounds checking, of course.

The fastest approach is to just hardcode the sums themselves.

```
s[0] = (x & (1<<0)) + (x & (1<<3)) + (x & (1<<6)) + (x & (1<<9));
```

etc. (The shifts occur at compile time.)

Comment: similar to the inital idea, this is not a very generic answer, but instead if implemented needs to use two loops. One is the one you wrote, the other one goes from 0 to m to do the adding and subtracting

Comment: It doesn't have to be generic. m is fixed at 3.

What do you mean by the second loop?

Comment: The hard code is fast for each by it's self. What about all together?